# Setup SVN repository on AWS for asp.net MVC 2 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to amazon web services (AWS). I have an asp.net MVC 2 website. I want to setup SVN repository on AWS. What do I need to do for this. I installed AWS toolkit for visual studio (http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/). I used amazon services RDS ( http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) to setup database instance and create database. I then got backup script  of the database from my local system and run on newly created amazon database. I then changed connectionstrings in code and deployed the code to amazon using AWS elastic beanstalk( http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). This is all related to deployment. Is there a better way to deploy asp.net MVC 2 website on AWS. Do I need to use EC2 ? What is its purpose ? How can I setup SVN repository on AWS?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother setting SVN up yourself - there are plenty of preconfigured amazon machine images that already have it done - for example

- https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007I9KE5C
- https://aws.amazon.com/amis/bitnami-subversion-stack-1-6-6-0-ebs

Just install these, and boom - it works.

As far as deployment goes, if you're new to AWS, I'd stay with Elastic Beanstalk at this point.  Personally, I usually have a build server and create a zip file and copy that to S3 to bootstrap my server installation.  You need the following to make it scaleable and available

- Load balancer
- 2 or more web servers
- Scaling group
- Security configuration
- Cloud Formation script to tie it all together

I wrote about [bootstrapping IIS on AWS](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/05/bootstrapping-on-aws/) which provides a bit more detail, but you'd need to add in your own RDS Cloud Formation, VPC and own requirements.  Not the easiest task though.